# Rails/Rspec/Capybara: Interpreting quotes for javascript string for execute script

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, capybara

Given that I need to set an element's selected index with javascript in capybara by the input name...

```
var element = document.querySelector("select[name='user[user_locations_attributes][0][location_attributes][state]']").selectedIndex = '50';
```

What is the proper way to interpret this as a string so it can be executed in Capybara with `execute_script(function_name_string)`? Because I keep getting syntax errors, unsure how to nest the " and ' quotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution to your question is to use a heredoc

```
page.execute_script <<~JS
  var element = document.querySelector("select[name='user[user_locations_attributes][0][location_attributes][state]']").selectedIndex = '50';
JS
```

Although if you have need for the element for anything else it's probably nicer to find the element in ruby and then just call execute_script on the element

```
el = find("select[name='user[user_locations_attributes][0][location_attributes][state]']")
el.execute_script('this.selectedIndex = 50;')
```

As a related question - is there a reason you're doing this via JS rather than just clicking on the correct option? If you're just scraping a page there's no issue, but if you're actually testing something this basically makes your test invalid since you could potentially be doing things a user couldn't

Since you commented that you are testing, you really shouldn't be doing this via JS, but should instead be using `select` or `select_option`.  select takes the options string (which you should have - otherwise why have a select element in the first place)

```
select('the text of option', from: 'user[user_locations_attributes][0][location_attributes][state]')
```

`select_option` is called on the option element directly, which can be found in a number of ways, such as

```
find("select[name='user[user_locations_attributes][0][location_attributes][state]'] option:nth-child(50)").select_option
```

Comment: Because the elements don't have ID's or anything to identify easily, I'm trying to just write tests without changing the frotn end.

Comment: By the way, you cant do ```el.execute_script``` you can only call execute_script on page, so I did that.

Comment: @zasman The ability to call `execute_script` on an element was added in Capybara 3.2 - so you're obviously running a very out-of-date version.   I've also updated my answer to show two methods that would be much better solutions than resulting to JS for this when testing.  If this has answered your question, don't forget to accept the answer (the checkmark) so the question gets marked as answered.

Comment: Hi, that makes sense ```  gem 'capybara', '2.6.2'``` thanks for the help.